# Missing arabic translations for material ui date pickers

Tags: material-ui

I was looking at the following folder: https://github.com/mui/mui-x/tree/next/packages/x-date-pickers/src/locales and there is no arabic locale. Does the x-date-pickers repository not support arabic? I'm pretty sure it used to when it was named `@material-ui/pickers` or something along those lines. Thanks.

Comment: Which `LocalizationProvider` are you using ?

Comment: @todevv date-fns

Answer (score 0):

You have to import Arabic Locale from `date-fns`

`import { arSA } from 'date-fns/locale';`

Comment: That doesn't translate the `okButtonLabel` from the link in my question. It formats the dates in arSA but it doesn't translate the actual picker fully.